# DLL Plugin Factory in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dll, plugins

## Problem

- Assume that I already have an application (a executable file with all source code). The source code has an `interface IShape` with class `Rectangle`, `Circle`, `Square` inherit from `IShape`. Main purpose of this application is to read data from file, calculate area and perimeter then print them on console.
- Because of many types of unknow shapes (triangle, ellipse, .etc) contain in my data file so I want to write a .dll file that can read these unknown shapes without rebuilt, rewrite existing code (but I can adjust a bit to handle DLL file better).
- How can I write a DLL file contain `class Triangle` which inherit from `interface IShape` contain in application?

## What I tried?

- I tried to write some .dll file but it just receive some primitive types (like int, double, wstring, .etc) and return a primitive types too.
- I don't know whether my idea is possible or not. But if it's possible, the result should like this:

### Application version 1

Cannot read Triangle.
Folder directory:

```
Application
|--run.exe
```

inheritance tree application version 1:

```
   IShape
   /    \
  /      \ 
Circle  Square
```

### Application version 2

Can read Triangle.
Folder directory:

```
Application
|--run.exe
|--Triangle.dll
```

Inheritance tree of application version 2:

```
        IShape
       /  |   \
      /   |    \ 
     /    |     \
Circle  Square   Triangle
```

Note that I use **explicit linking** method to link DLL file with main application.

Comment: Put the `IShape` in the dll or a different dll that both your dll and application depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is **exactly** what [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-objects-and-interfaces) solves. And if you use COM with the ATL classes (or the newer WinRT and cppwinrt stuff), you get a decent framework. It's just a bit of a learning curve.

But really all COM does for in-process DLLs do is to replace the manual work of invoking LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress with CoCreateInstance.

Manually, you can do this. First, your IShape interface needs to be nothing but pure virtual methods.

```
class IShape
{
   virtual int GetArea() = 0;
   // other 

};
```

Then each DLL exposes exports some sort of generic factory function:

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec( dllexport) IShape* __stdcall CreateShape(const char* shapeName, const char* shapeDescription)
    {
        if (std::string("triangle") == shapeName) 
        {
            return new Triangle(shapeDescription);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Where `Triange` is some class that inherits from `IShape` and implements all the pure virtual methods.

Then your EXE can do this for any given shape

```
typedef IShape* (__stdcall FN_CREATE_SHAPE)(const char* shapeName, const char* shapeDescription);

auto hMod = LoadLibrary("triangle.dll");

FN_CREATE_SHAPE fnCreateShape = (FN_CREATE_SHAPE)(GetProcAddress(hMod, "CreateShape"));

IShape* shape = fnCreateShape("triangle", "30,60,10x4... whatever you want here");    

int area = shape->GetArea();
```

I'll handwave my way out of explaining how the EXE knows the name and location of your extension DLLs. The registration and discovery problem can be solved with some registry keys, text file, or any way you want to do it.

Did I mention that COM does all of the above with a few nice things as well?

Comment: Did I miss something or is `extern "C"` missing here?

Comment: @fabian - good catch. I'll fix.